# Starting Oscillation in Sine Oscillator

Tags: oscillator

[image]

Here is a simplified digram of a sine wave oscillator (part of Colpits oscillator arrangement) stressing on the LC circuit. I am concentrating on the event at T = 0 sec.At the beginning, the inductor L2 would act as short and C3 and C4 will charge up to same potential. And here is my question, if the capacitors C3 and C4 charge up to same potential, then how on earth they discharge through the inductor L2.

I am guessing it won't, and let me take a step forward. Say voltage across C3 is fed back to the base of BJT (not shown in diagram). In that case collector current would increase, hence voltage across C4 would decrease, and **only then** the discharge process starts through the inductor as C3 is maintaining its starting potential. Hence can I state that the feedback is necessary to even start the discharging process through the inductor?

Is the above reasoning of mine correct??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the power is turned on, the voltage rises from 0V to 1V, however an inductor doesn't allow a current to change instantaneously.
It isn't a short but an open circuit at first, the current through L1 can only rise slowly.

A picture is worth a thousand words:
[image]

1. C4 is charged up
2. L1 starts to conduct
3. L1 is pulling current out of C4
4. C3 is fully charged, the current in L1 reverses
5. C3 gets discharged and C4 charges again

This is a view of the time domain, which is easy to understand. However frequency domains and state space can be better suited to do mathematical analysis, look at other answers for that.

Comment: So the inductor is an open circuit?????

Comment: Yes, in the beginning it is. That is one of the major features of an inductor. Also at 31k reputation, either I did something stupidly wrong, or you're not serious.

Comment: I *am* serious about clear exposition. If by 'blocking', you mean that an inductor requires a voltage across it to change the flow of current through it, then that's true (and not what you actually said), but irrelevant to starting an oscillator.

Comment: The thing I'm concerned about is if the inductor is 'blocking' initially, why do things change when it's started up? Sounds like magic. The 'to and fro' you describe might be a hand-waving description of how resonance works but it doesn't address how the thing starts. It does I suppose indirectly refute the OP's corresponding error, 'at the beginning, L2 is short'. It doesn't start, or at least need to start, in a single shot, as would a relaxation oscillator. The Ls and Cs need to be seen as components that affect the loop gain. The resonance mechanism should be a separate question.

Comment: It's not easy to answer a question where the OP starts off with something that's totally wrong. You've refuted it, but in a way that I don't find satisfactory. I've ignored it totally in my answer and described what is happening, but with no direct refutation, the OP might not 'get' what I'm implying. My answering policy though is that while I may not give exactly what the OP wants, I try to avoid confusing anybody. You're not the first. A month ago I had a week long discussion with a user with >150k rep on how transformer design questions should be answered properly.

Comment: I'm not rejecting your concern. I'll try to write a more precise description later

Comment: It's useful having this sort of discussion, because it's prompted me to 'revise up' my answer, to refute directly the 'mucking about with the tank component currents' that the OP had in his OP.

Comment: @Christian, I agree with Neil_UK (it makes no sense to analyze the LC circuit at t=0). Here is why: These considerations forget the positive feedback effect. That means: You are treating the whole circuit under loop gain aspects (open feedback path) only. That is not realistic. Instead, the closed loop behaviour must be analyzed. And this cannot be done step-by-step (starting at t=0). We only can say: The closed-loop pole pair has a small positive part and the circuit will exhibit self-excitement for that specific frequency only which fulfills the phase condition (zero loop phase).

Comment: The question is explicitly about t=0, also talking about poles and feedback loops is usually a bit to much for a beginner. Time domain is something everyone can understand, even if it's not the perfect way to describe a circuit.

Comment: Christian, OK - I understand. Are you using a simulation program? In ths case, I could recommend an interesting test.

Comment: @LvW I'm using LTSpice, what's your test? I also edited the answer to be a bit more clear about the inductor issue.

Comment: Simulate the impulse response of the tank circuit (alone) consisting of L2 in parallel with C3 in series with C4. For this purpose, connect (a) a resistor of app. 3kOhms between ground and the common node of L2 and C3 (replacing the base input resistance) and (b) inject a short voltage impuls into the 100 Ohm resistor. Watch the decaying oscillation across C3 and realize that the PHASE of the oscillation is shifted by 180deg if compared with the oscillation phase at the common node of C4 and L2. Hence, in conjunction with the transistors phase reversal we have 0 deg (positive feedback).

Answer (score 2):

There are two (maybe at least two) types of oscillator. Oscillators like this, which are basically linear amplifiers wrapped round a frequency selective circuit, and relaxation oscillators, which spend most of their time in a non-linear mode, typically charging or discharging a capacitor. When designing a relaxation oscillator, it is appropriate to work out how startup works, by looking at voltages and currents around the frequency determining components.

For this linear type of oscillator, it's usually *not* helpful to look at the frequency selective circuit (often called the 'tank' circuit) to figure out what's happening during startup. Any resonance in those components is part of the loop gain, and for that you need the steady state.

In real life (as opposed to simulation), there are two ways that an oscillator like this can start. There's the quick way, through any switch-on transient. If that doesn't work, then there's the slow way, through amplification of circuit noise.

In simulation, often neither method works. The initial DC solver often works 'too well', and leaves no transient to start things. If you are not modelling noise, and few people bother to, then there will be no noise to amplify either. Starting an oscillator like this in simulation usually needs either setting 'initial conditions' in one of the tank components to create a transient, or the injection of a pulse after t0.

All startup routes require that the circuit has more than unity gain (exactly unity gain being not only impossible to achieve, but also would give an infinitely long start-up), at some frequency determined by the tank circuit. If it's less than one, even an initial transient will die away, so gain >1 is needed for the build up of oscillation.

As the signal builds up, eventually when it is large enough, due to transistor cutoff($) for part of the cycle, the *average* gain will drop to unity, and the oscillation amplitude stops increasing. You can also have gain control feedback, but it's not always worth the complication.

($) What most people get wrong is to limit the oscillation with transistor saturation rather than cutoff, the difference is how the transistor is biassed. With saturation limiting, the frequency is far more susceptible to rail variations (which also means rail noise conversion to phase noise) and to temperature, and the device goes low impedance which de-Qs the tank, rather than high impedance which doesn't.

Comment: If there wouldn`t be a power switch-on transient - yes, the noise would be responsible for start of oscillations. However, each oscillator is switched-on sometime - and this switch-on puls creates a transient which causes self excitement of the circuit. Remember how the response of an RLC tank looks like after a short impuls is applied.

Comment: Now - after the contribution was edited - I fully agree with the above. However, one small comment: Speaking about "more than unity gain" I suppose you mean "unity loop gain ".

Comment: I've added an edit to clarify that more than unity gain is indeed needed for small signal conditions, and how it is brought back to exactly unity gain with a large signal. I've also updated to reflect a conversation I had with Christian about whether we should look at the tank to figure out startup (I don't think we should)

Comment: Yes - I am with you. I have given a corresponding comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider 2 scenarios for DC bias time constants.

- a)  Slow R1C4=T1 >> 1/f  where f is the resonance of LC
- b)  Fast R1C4=T1 << 1/f

a) Slow

DC voltage rises slowly and the current thru R1 is a fairly linear Ramp meaning the DC charge current greatly exceeds the ac current resonating in LC loop. The AC loop current, Ipp is equal to the initial Idc = V/R1. OK?

b) Fast

The 1st cap C4 charges up swiftly with a derivative current of the step voltage looking like a narrow spike and the AC current again as above starts at the initial DC current V/R1 but the smaller T also reduces the Q of the parallel resonant circuit such that it dampens out very quickly.

If L was increased significantly (1H) to raise the Q there would be almost no AC current in the 1st Cap C4 and all the AC current flows thru the [**outer loop of  R1 L2 C3 V+**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2014.235633750745258%2058%205%2043%0As%20128%2080%20176%2080%200%200%20false%0Ac%20176%2080%20176%20144%200%200.000001%204.996698744321849%0Al%20176%2080%20240%2080%200%201%200.003302864158342777%0Av%2064%20144%2064%2080%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%2064%2080%20128%2080%200%201%0Aw%2064%20144%20176%20144%200%0Aw%20176%20144%20240%20144%200%0Ac%20240%2080%20240%20144%200%200.000001%203.391521420541271%0Aw%20240%2080%20304%2080%200%0Aw%20240%20144%20304%20144%200%0Ao%201%2064%200%204097%2010%200.00009765625%200%202%201%203%0Ao%207%2064%200%204097%200.3125%200.00625%201%202%207%203%0Ao%204%2064%200%204097%205%200.00625%202%202%204%203%0Ao%204%2064%200%204097%205%200.00625%203%202%204%203%0A)

Answer (score 0):

What do you regard as T=0? I'll assume its when you connect V2. Here's the initial transient:
[image: initial transient capacitor voltage and inductor current]
 At t=0+ all capacitor voltages and inductor current are zero. Inductor current (red) will finally settle at zero. Capacitor voltage eventually rises to supply voltage of 1v. At the end of this 10uS run, capacitor voltage has risen to about 47mV due to the RC time constant of 200 microseconds (C3 + C4 are in parallel for the charging time constant).
But note that the two capacitor voltages **at the resonant frequency** are equally opposing each other.